# Публикация приложений в Google Play из России

Tags: google-play

Планирую опубликовать бесплатное приложение в Google Play, хочу зарегистрировать аккаунт разработчика. Знаю, что гугл запретила разработчикам выгружать в каталог Google Play платные приложения для Android. Распространяются ли данные ограничения на бесплатные приложения на данный момент?

Есть ли какие то дополнительные ограничения, о которых мне стоит знать заранее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я смог зарегистрировать аккаунт разработчика, оплатил взнос и успешно опубликовал бесплатные приложения. Кроме платных приложений, пока, ограничений не выявил. Единственное, если делать оплату внутри приложения через сторонний сервис, то делать ее только для России, для иностранных граждан по прежнему нужно использовать платежную систему Google Play.

Comment: оплачивал через российскую карту?

Comment: нет, использовал сторонний сервис, предоставляющий карту США

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что российские карты не пропускает?

Comment: Честно, я даже и не пробовал. Visa и Mastercard не принимают платежи за рубежом, во всех сервисах где я пробовал платить российской картой, ее не принимали. Вы конечно можете попробовать, но я сильно сомневаюсь что получится.

Comment: большое спасибо!

Comment: Российской картой не удалось оплатить(
Буду пробовать через сервисы